# Read non delimited asciif file Apache Pig Latin

Tags: parsing, apache-pig, hadoop2, bigdata

I'm trying to read a text file in Apache Pig Latin that has non-delimited ascii comprising each row. That is, each column in that row begins and ends at a  specific position in the row.

Sample definition:

```
+--------+----------------+--------------+
| Column | Start Position | End Position |
+--------+----------------+--------------+
| A      | 1              | 6            |
+--------+----------------+--------------+
| B      | 8              | 11           |
+--------+----------------+--------------+
| C      | 13             | 15           |
+--------+----------------+--------------+
```

Sample Data:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8  | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| s | a | m | p | l | e |   | d  | a | t  | a  |    |    | h  | i  |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| d | u | d | e |   |   |   | hi |   |    |    |    | b  | r  | o  |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Expected Output:

```
sample, data, hi
dude, hi, bro
```

How do I read this in Pig? PigStorage doesn't seem flexible enough to allow positional delimiting, only string delimiting (comma, tab, etc..).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Apache provides a loader for this specific use case:

```
LOAD 'data.txt' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.FixedWidthLoader('1-6, 8-11, 13-15', 'SKIP_HEADER') AS (a, b, c);
```

https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.16.0/api/